# Issue Inserting Records Into MySQL With Express and Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am having an issue where my `INSERT` code is not working. I am able to select data from the database but I cannot add data. When I run `http://18.219.103.143:3000/insert-user?fname=new&lname=user&email=ejw&password=hsdf` I get a server error in the console. 
[image]

I'm thinking there is something wrong with this `app.get`.

```
app.get('/insert-user',function(req,res,next){
  var context = {};
  pool.query("INSERT INTO user (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 
  [req.query.fname, req.query.lname, req.query.email, req.query.password], 
  function(err, result){
    if(err){
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('home',context);
  });
});
```

However, I am not able to get any messages to print to the console in order to debug. But, I would think since I can connect to the database with my `SELECT` statements that connecting is not the issue. It's almost as if the `app.get` INSERT isn't even being executed. Does anyone have an idea of an effective way to debug this? I am hitting a wall and cannot figure out what the best next step is.

Comment: As an aside, it's an anti-pattern to use `GET` rather than `POST` to... post data. 

Comment: Your browser console error message complains  about a .css file. Is that what you expected? Can you try hitting that css file directly? What appears in your node.js console? Can you stick a console.log or two into your node.js to see how far it got?

Comment: debug what's the error you are probable getting in `err`. You might be getting that error 500 because you don't have a proper handle to follow the `next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first look in your terminal where you're running your server. If there's nothing already being output there I would modify your script to the following

```
app.get('/insert-user',function(req,res,next){
  var context = {};
  pool.query("INSERT INTO user (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 
  [req.query.fname, req.query.lname, req.query.email, req.query.password], 
  function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err); // <= add this
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('home',context);
  });
});
```

Then try hitting your your endpoint again. Hopefully the details of the error get logged (in the terminal, not your browser).

Comment: This worked for me. I originally was running `forever` which was preventing any of the error messages from showing. Switched to `node` and error messages showed. The error was just that some of the default fields were not being populated. Thanks!